# Trouble remapping <c-h> in vim normal mode

Tags: vim

I have the following in my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <c-h> zh
nnoremap <c-j> <c-e>
nnoremap <c-k> <c-y>
nnoremap <c-l> zl
```

and nmap reports the following mappings

```
n  <C-H>       * zh
n  <NL>        * <C-E>
n  <C-K>       * <C-Y>
n  <C-L>       * zl
```

The main problem I have is that `<c-h>` hasn't actually been remapped to `zh`. `<c-h>` still acts as the default behavior, which just moves the cursor left.

I've done this in a clean `.vimrc` file so it's not due to a plugin collision. This is happening with vim 7.4 on a redhat 7.2 system that I remote into from putty. I've tried to replicate this on my windows machine using WSL but it works as expected there.

The minor problem is the second row of nmap, why does it say `<NL>` instead of `<C-J>` The mapping seems to be behaving as expected.

Comment: `<NL>` is the same motion as `<c-j>`. see `:h <NL>`. Your `<c-h>` map should work. Is `wrap` off? Are you pressing control and not shift?

Comment: You should extend your question with the following information: Vim or gVim, OS and terminal-emulator. With that info, someone with a similar setup might be able to reproduce the problem. I can't reproduce the `<c-h>` problem on Ubuntu with gVim or Vim in gnome-terminal.

Comment: info added, vim 7.4, redhat 7.2, putty.

Comment: `<C-h>` is the same as `<BS>` and it highly depends on what code point is your terminal emulator sending. What does the `<c-v><c-h>` output in the insert mode?

Comment: `^H`, so it looks like putty is sending the correct keyboard code?

Comment: I found a setting in putty->terminal->keyboard setting `change the sequence sent by` ... `the backspace key` with options `Control-H` or `Control-?`. I switched from `?` to `h` and now my vim mapping works as I want. Oddly switching back to `?` doesn't change the behavior back to backspace instead of my mapping.